# .htaccess file extension removal not working (lots of solutions tried)

Tags: apache, file, .htaccess, webserver

I've trawled through Google for days on end now trying to find a solution to my problem, patching in segments of code to no avail. Nothing has worked. I just want to remove the file extension .shtml from my URL but NOTHING works. I've made sure the file is being updated and my website isn't being loading from cache and all that malarcky. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong, please?

Only thing I can think of is that my web hosting (Hostgator) doesn't have the Apache mod_rewrite enabled?

```
RewriteEngine On

#Remove file extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.shtml -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.shtml [L]

#Add trailing slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mythofechelon.co.uk/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First thing first make sure your .htaccess is being read. Put some garbage text and see if you get 500 error in browser.

Comment: The block in my question was only a segment of the file. The other components (DirectoryIndex and ErrorDocument, for example) work successfully.

Comment: But I did that anyway, and, yes, I got a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of your extension removing code have this code instead:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.shtml to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.shtml [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.shtml$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.shtml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.shtml$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.shtml -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.shtml [L
```

**Adding Trailing Slash**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

However keep in mind that even a URI of `http://domain.com/foo#aaa` will become `http://domain.com/foo/#aaa` because there is no way to detect `#` from mod_rewrite since that is handled entirely by browsers.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Do you also know how to put the trailing slash on the end of the URL? And will that code work for any other file extensions just the ones you've manually typed there (I'm assuming you'll have to create a block for each extension)

Comment: You're welcome. I have added code to add trailing slash but there is a caveat that `#` will also have slash.

Comment: The code didn't work that time. :/

No worries, my main aim was to eliminate the file extension. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Does the same thing.

Comment: Just added that to the #Remove file extensions block and it didn't work.

Comment: Removed everything except for that code and it still didn't work. :(