# URL rewriterule to clean extensions

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite, dns

I´m looking for a RewriteRule to clean URL´s. I already have a rule where pages can be found that are just `/file` instead of `/file.ext`. The problem is that when entering a page like `/file.ext` it will be equal to that instead of `/file` what I want it to be.

Now I recognized that this makes things harder than they are because when setting a link I need them to set without extension. Otherway round it would be much easier to set the original filename incl. extension and setting apache to rewrite/delete the extension.

It would be great if someone could help me out. The common extensions are php, html and htm.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are searching is here: [.htaccess file extension removal not working (lots of solutions tried)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909386/htaccess-file-extension-removal-not-working-lots-of-solutions-tried) 
See the accepted answer, it is based on the .shtml file extension. You have to copy these rules for every file extension you want to use and replace .shtml with your file extension. 
 **Be careful**: If you have two files *index.html* and *index.php* and you use the rules for .php and .html, only the first match will work. So choose different file names for different.

```
RewriteEngine on
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.htm to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.htm [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.htm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.htm$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.htm [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Also note that this is still kind of "inefficient". For every request sent to the server, for example /file, it will try at first to find file.html. If it doesn't find it, it will look for file.htm. If it doesn't find it, it will look for file.php. Only after it didn't find file.php, the 404 will follow. For adding more filters for file extensions the inefficiency will increase.